# Find illegal character \0 in Netbeans

Tags: java, regex, netbeans

I have a file opened in netbeans with last line filled with character `\0`. This character remains invisible and cause netbeans to give 'illegal character' error.

I tried finding in Nebeans with `[\\0]`, `[\0]`, `\0`, `\\0` with Regular Expression checked but no luck. `[\0]` and `\0` gives 'illegal octal escape sequence error'.

I can easily find and replace \0 using Notepad++ from this file. How to do it in Netbeans?

Comment: Just select the line and delete?

Comment: Select and Delete works, but it is not just one file. Also find replace should have solution and work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `\0`, I assume you mean the ASCII `NUL` character with an ASCII value of zero (or the equivalent Unicode character whose escape sequence in Java is `\u0000`).

To find this character in the Netbeans find dialog using regular expressions, the proper escape sequences to use are either the control sequence `\c@`, the hexadecimal sequence `\x00`, the octal sequence `\00`, or the Unicode sequence `\u0000`. Note that the formatting of each of these sequences matters, and is documented by the [`Pattern` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Your attempt at using `\0` did not work because that sequence indicates the beginning of an octal sequence, but you did not provide the actual octal number (the first zero following the slash is a marker, not actually part of the octal number). The typical *Nix `\0` escape is not recognized by `Pattern`.

For example, putting `\u0000` in the "Find:" field of the Find and Replace function, and putting *(NUL)* in the "Replace:" field, with the "Regular Expression" option checked, will replace all instances of the `NUL` character with the five-character string *(NUL)*. This will work in either the Find and Replace for a single open file, or for an entire project using the *Edit* | *Replace in projects...* dialog.

Comment: Netbeans gives "illegal charachter: \0" error. Notepad++ shows it as `nul`

Comment: I have solved this illegal error in an illegal way, i'll try this method when encountered again.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 7.3 (development version), and have yet to see it complain about a file containing a `NUL` character, so I'm not sure where the "illegal character" message is coming from. Might be from a code parser. I've been testing with only text (.txt) files.

Comment: \u0000 worked fine, but only finds single character at a time and netbeans use to stop after finding 5000 results.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Netbeans had a find limit. That's good to know. You can always try `\u0000+` to find sequences of one or more nul characters. Maybe the limit is find instances and not number of characters.